# Configuring hawtio with JNDIRealm on tomcat?

Tags: hawtio

I'm trying to use active directory authentication on hawtio login. 
I've defined the JNDIRealm on my server.xml and enabled authentication on tomcat catalina options - but couldn't get the hawt to use this realm.
I saw that hawt website presents that the default behavior on tomcat is using users data file (tomcat-users.xml) - and I succeed using it as described in website.
But is there any way to work with JNDIRealm instead this default UserDatabaseRealm behavior?

Any help appreciated.
Thx.

Comment: hawtio works with JAAS. So if you can configure Tomcat to offer JAAS, then you may be able to do this.

Comment: @ClausIsben Thx for clarifying it - I couldn't find anywhere to mention it loud & clear.
For anyone looking how to do it here's a link to an article (got it from hawtio site: http://jcordes73.blogspot.de/2014/03/hawtio-authentication-with-ldap-on.html)

Comment: Yeah we got a bunch of links for hawtio articles/blogs/videos here - http://hawt.io/articles/index.html